# Can't access a property which is defined and appears in console

Tags: javascript

I can't understand my JavaScript issue. I have this property:

```
this.ref.tileWidth = this.width / 32;
```

Then in a prototype function I have:

```
console.log(this);
console.log(this.tileWidth);
```

Now look at the outputs...

[image: console]
Why does the second console.log display `undefined`? In the first one `tileWidth` is clearly defined. I don't understand why I can't access this property.

More code:

```
function Tileset(url) {    
    this.image = new Image();
    this.image.ref = this;
    this.image.onload = function(){
        if(!this.complete) throw new Error('Error when loading the tileset:' + url +   '');
        this.ref.tileWidth = this.width / 32;
    }
    this.image.src = 'tilesets/'+url;
}

Tileset.prototype.drawTile = function(number, context, xDestination, yDestination) {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.tileWidth);
}
```

Comment: what's defined as `this`? Also try; `console.log(this.ref.tileWidth);`

Comment: Doesn't work, this.ref save the reference in the constructor.
You have the output of this in the screen

Comment: Could you show some more code?

Comment: not sure how you expect others to help troubleshoot without providing some context

Comment: added my Tileset.js example

Comment: That output is absolutely unreadable. Don't take a screenshot of text output, just copy it into the question.

Comment: Copy the source url of the image to your browser

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/o1HzR.png

Comment: Maybe you should look at this output: http://i.stack.imgur.com/FPaU3.png

The second output is in the onload, the little difference is that tileWidth property appear directly (when is not expanded), on the other log the property appear only when its expanded, very strange...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an onload issue, Its seems I try to read the property but the onload code is executed after my console.log (async problem maybe)

If I use a setTimeout its working

Answer (score 0):

The variable *this* in the context of the onload callback is the image, not the *this* of your tileset function.

A basic example:

```
function newObject() {
    this.x = 42;
    this.img = new Image();
    this.img.src = "image.png";
    this.img.onload = function() {
        console.log(this.width); //Outputs the width of the image
        console.log(this.x); //undefined in this context
        //EDIT: x is actually a property of the Image object, but it would equal 0, not 42
    };
}
```

You can create a temporary variable to hold the context in order to access it in your onload callback.

```
function newObject() {
    this.x = 42;
    this.img = new Image();
    this.img.src = "image.png";
    var _this = this;
    this.img.onload = function() {
        console.log(this.width); //Outputs the width of the image
        console.log(_this.x); //Outputs 42
    };
}
```

Comment: Hmm it's exactly what I've done:
this.image.ref = this;

Then on the the image onload I should access ref by this.ref

And the property appear in the console.log, that's what I don't understand